# Maximum clique size of an edge disjoint union

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a simple but not necessarily finite graph, and let $E',E''$ be a disjoint partitioning of $E$ into two (not necessarily finite) subsets, so that $G$ is the edge disjoint union of the graphs $G'=(V,E')$ and $G''=(V,E'')$.

**My (admittedly vague) question is:** when can the maximum clique size of $G$ be related to the maximum clique sizes of $G'$ and $G''$? In the case that $G$ is infinite, is it even clear that maximum clique size of $G$ and $G'$ both finite implies that the maximum clique size of $G$ is finite?

I'm guessing that in complete generality probably little can be said, because a clique of $G$ need not a priori respect the clique structures of $G'$ and $G''$. But in my setting, I have a particular pair of graphs $G', G''$ that I know a little bit about- both are infinite and locally infinite, both have finite maximum cliques (and I know these sizes explicitly), both have finite chromatic number, they're bi-lipschitz equivalent to each other, etc. So I'd also be happy with results that assume extra structure (but not finiteness) on $G,G',G''$.

Thanks for reading; any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather general question, and I am certainly not in a position to give an exhaustive answer - but here. at least, is an answer to your particular question as to whether the clique sizes of $G'$ and $G''$ being finite implies that the clique size of $G$ is finite. So, the answer is **yes** -- by the basic [Ramsey's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem). If you had arbitrarily large cliques in $G$, then you could partition the edges of arbitrarily large complete graph into two sets with the clique sizes of the subgraphs induced by these sets being bounded, in a direct contradiction with the aforementioned theorem.

Comment: thank you for your response- it seems Ramsey's theorem works quite well to answer the finiteness question.

Comment: basil, Ramsey's theorem will also give you reasonable bounds on the clique number of $G$.  If the clique numbers of $G'$ and $G''$ are $r$ and $s$, then the clique number of $G$ must be less than $R(r+1, s+1) \leq \binom {r+s} r$.

Answer (score 1):

Maria Chudnovsky and Juba Ziani have [an arXiv paper up today](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6443) in which they say something about this problem for finite graphs.

> Let $B$ and $R$ be two simple graphs with vertex set $V$, and let
>   $G(B,R)$ be the simple graph with vertex set $V$, in which two
>   vertices are adjacent if they are adjacent in at least one of $B$ and
>   $R$. For $X \subseteq V$, we denote by $B|X$ the subgraph of $B$
>   induced by $X$; let $R|X$ and $G(B,R)|X$ be defined similarly. We say
>   that the pair $(B,R)$ is *additive* if for every $X \subseteq V$,
>   the sum of the clique numbers of $B|X$ and $R|X$ is at least the
>   clique number of $G(B,R)|X$. In this paper we give a necessary and
>   sufficient characterization of additive pairs of graphs. This is a
>   numerical variant of a structural question studied in $[1]$.